# Hacer un .replace() a este caracter: "/" Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Tengo una duda que no he podido encontrar en google. Lo que pasa es que quiero aplicar un **.replace global**  un string, por lo que lo haría algo así:

```
let str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
let res = str.replace(/blue/g, "red");
```

Todo bien ahí, pero mi problema es cuando quiero reemplazar un **/**, lo que seria así:

```
let res = str.replace(///g, "red");
```

pero el replace lo interpreta como si estuviera cerrando el campo de "busqueda" por así decirlo.

Como le harían ustedes?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que usar el caracter de escape `\`.
Para reemplazar '/' por "red" sería lo siguiente:

`let res = str.replace(/\//g, "red");`